# Is income tax a revenue-based tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

Recently I was discussing taxes and politics with a family member and they highlighted the difference between how corporations and citizens are taxed.

- Corporations pay tax on profits --not revenue. This means that if a corporation makes $1m in profits, but has $800k in spending, they would only be taxed on the remaining $200k. This amount can be further decreased by reinvesting it into the company.
- Citizens, on the other hand, are taxed based on their income (which is comparable to revenue). For example, if a citizen has an income of $80k and a spending (e.g. rent, educational loans, groceries) of $60k, they still get taxed on the $80k rather than the $20k (comparable to profit).

To my knowledge, this is correct. Is there a flaw in this understanding, i.e. is it reasonable to classify income tax as a revenue tax? Why was this made like this, what's the history behind it?

Comment: Are you referring to just salaries and wages? Capital gains tax works differently.

Comment: US income tax allows many expenses to be excluded or deducted (some only if you itemize) or reduce your tax via credits (both often with limits and/or phaseouts), though not rent and food: many retirement plans and IRAs; state&local taxes (not both income&sales); health coverage, and expenses exceeding a floor; contributions to charity; home mortgage interest; adoption and supporting dependents; most higher education costs and school loan interest; unreimbursed disaster losses; some energy-efficiency equipment; and quite a few rarer ones.

Comment: as @dave_thompson_085 says that is indeed precisely what happens.   Recall too that over in the US vast numbers file as self-employed (I believe an amazing 10% !), and self-employed is just the same as "a company", and then the scenario the OP paints for companies indeed happens identically for those individuals.

Answer (score 2):

- The term "revenue tax" really has little/no meaning. Different writers, economists, would happen to define it in different ways. (I've never really heard the term, it sounds a bit whacky.)  Note that "definition" questions are largely meaningless. You're literally just "re-asking" what we will "decide this means". If you say "rent and groceries *are* included in revenue tax calculations" and I say "rent and groceries *are not* included in revenue tax calculations" - so what?  I could just choose a different word for my usage, and/or you could choose a different word for your usage.
- One big thing you are missing. Self-employed people of course *also* only pay tax on profits.  Just like a company.  "A self-employed person" is just a business.  If a client has me build a fancy machine and they pay me $200k and the machine costs me $100k, obviously I only pay tax on $100k. (Thank God!) So there's no difference at all, in that sense, between how a small business (ie "a human") and a company are taxed.
- If your contention is that people "should" be allowed to first subtract the cost of rent/groceries.  I'm all for it!  :)  But the immediate objection is, *those costs have nothing to do with* the "business".  See? The company making cars, obviously deducts the cost of steel and paint.  But of course, they can't deduct the cost of groceries!  Similarly, someone arguing against you, would say that for a person working at McDonalds, the cost of their groceries has nothing to do with that "business".  I would note that many people indeed **do** believe that humans who are employed, should, be able to deduct the cost of regular *commuting*, since indeed that is 100% entirely part of the "business of having that job" (whereas, as I mention, "groceries" say just has nothing to do with it.
- Recall too that many think corporate taxes are completely stupid. Consider any company. It makes a million in profit.  Pretend for a sec there are no corporate taxes. What happens to the million dollars?  It goes to Mars?  Of course not, corporations don't exist, they're a fiction, the entire million dollars goes to one person or another!  (The owners, workers, shareholders - whatever.)  And then of course obviously it is taxed.  Corporate tax is utterly pointless, it probably results in *less* tax take for a government.

Comment: Money could just sit in the corporation's bank account until it needs to spend it. Without corporate taxes, money could bounce around for many cycles between corporations spending it on their business without ever going to an individual. The government taxes corporations to make sure it gets a cut of that.

Comment: @Daniel , by all means, some folks would and do make that argument.  (For me the argument is wrong:  say Ford has $1m and somehow "just gives" it to Apple (literally some sort of bank transfer), the scenario you present would be correct. But what happens is, Ford buys (say) one thousand iPhones with the $1m. That money flows straight to the experts in Korea building iPhones. Every dollar taken away from the $1m on tax, fails to flow to Korean electronics experts. And so on down the line.)  Again - that's just my take, many agree with what you said totally. the point here...

Comment: ...  the whole point here is the question is not answerable.  It's one of the "big questions of society-politics" and it certainly can't just be "answered".  Also, the question was about "revenue?" tax which I tried to explaion in that context.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the way it works. You may feel that's unfair, but consider that corporations and business actually can't pay taxes. At the end of the day, it's always a real human paying the tax anyway, even if a business is the vehicle by which the tax is collected.

Historically, it was done this way because it makes the most sense. If you tax people on savings (income minus expenses), then you're penalizing people who save. If you tax a business on revenue, you'll end up taxing businesses that have a lot of revenue, but not a lot of profit. Those business might still be adding value to society - just not earning tons of profit at that moment.